# Creating New Relic Plugin Dashboards in the plugin agent code

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

Collaborating on a plugin agent for a New Relic plugin is easy on GitHub, but the creation of plugin dashboards is tied to a single New Relic account. I don't want to give the world access to my New Relic account for obvious reasons. Is there a way to include the dashboard specification in the plugin agent rather than tying it to a New Relic account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to include the dashboard specification in the agent.

If you wish to collaborate with multiple people on the dashboard portion of the plugin, but do not wish to add them to your New Relic account, you can sign up for a new 'lite' account and add everyone you want to collaborate with.

https://newrelic.com/docs/subscriptions/mixing-subscription-levels